# Foursquare API over Axios (Ajax) in Laravel not returning any data (500 internal server error)

Tags: ajax, laravel, api, axios, foursquare

So I'm trying to get company details via the Foursquare API after a user gives in a business name and a location name. 
For example: "Huntrs" and "Brussel" should get this business' details via Foursquare API and then return them.

So far i'm trying to do this over Axios to make an Ajax call within the Laravel framework.

ajax.js - Axios call:

```
//Ajax function to get company details when the getCompanyDetails() function is called on a btn click
function getCompanyDetails(){

    //Get company name and location from form
    let businessName =  document.querySelector('#businessName').innerHTML;
    let businessLocation = document.querySelector('#businessLocation').innerHTML;

    //Make the actual API GET request
    axios.post('/getcompanydetails', {
        params: {
          businessName: businessName,
          businessLocation: businessLocation 
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);

        //Add response data to empty form fields
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        //Log request error in console, maybe also show onpage?
        console.log(error);
    })

}
```

web.php - Routing

```
Route::post('/getcompanydetails', 'AjaxController@getCompanyDetails'); //Route for ajax call made from JS file ajax.js
```

AjaxController.php - Controller that handles Guzzle request to API for ajax calls

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    //Make Foursquare API request with Guzzle!
    public function getCompanyDetails() {

        //Get params back from the Axios get Request
        $params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
        $location = $params['businessLocation'];
        $companyName = $params['businessName'];

        //Setup actual Guzzle request
        $client = new Client();
        $result = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search', [
            'query' => [
                'client_id' => env('FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID'),
                'client_secret' => env('FOURSQUARE_SECRET_ID'),
                'v' => "20191009",
                'near' => $location,
                'query' => $companyName,
                'limit' => 1
            ]
        ]);

        //Return $result in JSON format to ajax.js
        return response()->json($result);

     }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Saly 3301 said i had to check the network tab:
network -> preview tab in chrome dev tools
This said the businessLocation index was undefined.

Solution:
Within the ajax.js, I removed the params{} around my actual name and location parameters and that stops the 500 internal error.

As such:

```
axios.post('/getcompanydetails', {
          businessName: businessName,
          businessLocation: businessLocation
    })
```